# Finding where HHVM service is started automatically

Tags: php, ubuntu, homestead

Not sure what happened to cause this, but my Homestead vagrant box is running HHVM without the appropriate `Homestead.yaml` config flag to get it started on `vagrant up`. This is causing problems with running PHP on my box.

How do I find where in the system the process is being started so I can prevent it from auto-starting each boot?